# Reset the date portion to the first of the month while preserving the time

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to reset the date portion to the first of the month while preserving the time?
For example:

```
2018-01-02 23:00:00 -> 2018-01-01 23:00:00
2018-04-04 10:00:00 -> 2018-04-01 10:00:00
```

Comment: what do you mean by "*trunc days*"?

Comment: Sure, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example:

```
select sysdate, sysdate + (trunc(sysdate, 'mm') - trunc(sysdate)) as other_date
from   dual;

SYSDATE             OTHER_DATE         
------------------- -------------------
2018-04-06 10:17:47 2018-04-01 10:17:47
```

Obviously, there is no simple way to do this (you have to admit it's an unusual requirement).

Equivalent arithmetic:

```
trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + (sysdate - trunc(sysdate))
```

Use whichever you find easier to understand right away. In both cases, what you have in the parentheses after the + sign is a difference of two dates, which is a number (measured in days) which can be added to a date (the expression BEFORE the + sign).

Answer (score 3):

```
with x as (
  select to_date( '2018-01-02 23:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as d from dual
  union all
  select to_date(  '2018-04-04 10:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') from dual
)


SELECT d, d - trunc( d ) + trunc( d, 'MM' )
FROM x;

D                   D-TRUNC(D)+TRUNC(D,
------------------- -------------------
2018-01-02 23:00:00 2018-01-01 23:00:00
2018-04-04 10:00:00 2018-04-01 10:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
ts - ((extract(day from ts)-1))
```

Comment: Right... but the other solutions can be generalized easily to copy the time-of-day to the first day of the quarter, or year, etc. Not as easily done with EXTRACT().

Comment: @mathguy: Of course, but the op asked explicitly for the first of the *month* and it's an unusual requirement anyway :-)